# iscsiadm: Login I/O error, failed to receive a PDU

Tags: linux, iscsi

I'm trying to discover an iscsi target and am getting the following error:

```
iscsiadm: Connection to Discovery Address 172.18.1.4 closed
iscsiadm: Login I/O error, failed to receive a PDU
```

My target config is the following:

```
<target iqn.2012-4.com.mylab:first >
    backing-store /dev/vgsrv/storage
    initiator-address 172.18.1.1
</target>
```

Here are my details:

```
my initiator IP : 172.18.1.4
my target IP : 172.18.1.1
kernel : Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 
iscsid version 6.2.0-873.13.el6
```

Any tips why I'm facing this issue? All firewalls and ips are off.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you you have your target and initiator IP addresses correct. Then, try running iscsiadm with the debug flag, e.g.:

sh# iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -d8 -p TARGETS_IP_ADDRESS

The debugging output should help you track down your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's some confusion with IP addresses?  This error:

```
Connection to Discovery Address 172.18.1.4 closed
```

That address should be the address of your target, to which iscsiadm connects (via iscsid) for discovery.   But 172.18.1.4 is the address of your initiator, supplied below "here is my details".  However, in the configuration, you list the initiator as 172.18.1.1.

Comment: Yes, and you have your target set up incorrectly if your statements are accurate. The initiator address listed in your target configuration looks to be wrong.